# Total number of inserted rows when in a loop

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert

Due to a full transaction log, I am dividing my large `INSERT`s like this:

```
DECLARE @rc INT = 1;
WHILE @rc > 0
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO MyTargetTable (Id, SendId, RecipientId)
    SELECT TOP (500000) SendRecipientId, SendId, RecipientId
    FROM #SendRecipients AS s
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM MyTargetTable AS t
        WHERE t.Id  = s.SendRecipientId
    ) 
    ORDER BY SendRecipientId
  SET @rc = @@ROWCOUNT;
  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END;
```

How can I get the total number of inserted rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add another variable to sum the `@@rowcount` - you might need to use a `bigint` and not `int`.

```
DECLARE @rc INT = 1, @total bigint = 0;
WHILE @rc > 0
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO MyTargetTable (Id, SendId, RecipientId)
    SELECT TOP (500000) SendRecipientId, SendId, RecipientId
    FROM #SendRecipients AS s
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM MyTargetTable AS t
        WHERE t.Id  = s.SendRecipientId
    ) 
    ORDER BY SendRecipientId
  SELECT @rc = @@ROWCOUNT, @Total += @@ROWCOUNT;
  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END;
```

Comment: thank you. let me try this out and come back to you.

Comment: Thank you for the right answer. I had written `SET` first instead of `SELECT` in the `@@ROWCOUNT` line. So I got weird results. Slightly strange that one should write `SELECT` to set a variable. But that is apparently the way to do it.

Comment: With `SET` you can only set one variable at the time, with `select` you can set multiple variables. Anyway, glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this - updated your query.

```
DECLARE @rc INT = 0;
WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO MyTargetTable (Id, SendId, RecipientId)
    SELECT TOP (500000) SendRecipientId, SendId, RecipientId
    FROM #SendRecipients AS s
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM MyTargetTable AS t
        WHERE t.Id  = s.SendRecipientId
    ) 
    ORDER BY SendRecipientId
  SET @rc = @rc + @@ROWCOUNT;
  COMMIT TRANSACTION;

  IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
  BEGIN
    BREAK;
  END

END;
```